# extract substring with regular expression

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string, actually is a directory file name.

```
str='\\198.168.0.10\share\ccdfiles\UA-midd3-files\UA0001A_15_Jun_2014_08.17.49\Midd3\y12m05d25h03m16.midd3'
```

I need to extract the target substring  `'UA0001A'` with matlab (well I would like think all tools should have same syntax). 
It does not necessary to be exact `'UA0001A'`, it is arbitrary alphabet-number combination. 
To make it more general, I would like to think the substring (or the word) shall satisfy

1. it is a alphabet-number combination word
2. it cannot be pure alphabet word or pure number word
3. it cannot include `'midd'` or `'midd3'` or `'Midd3'` or `'MIDD3'`, etc, so may use case-intensive method to exclude word begin with `'midd'`
4. it cannot include `'y[0-9]{2,4}m[0-9]{1,2}d[0-9]{1,2}\w*'`

How to write the regular expression to find the target substring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the substring always delimited by "\" and "_"? this would make things much easier

Comment: I would like to think it should be separated by a non-(alphabet or number) character such as '\','.',' ','-','_', etc that can occur in the directory file name.

Comment: Try [`regexp(s, '(?i)\\(?![^\W_]*(midd|y\d+m\d+))(?=[^\W_]*\d)(?=[^\W_]*[a-zA-Z])([^\W_]+)','tokens');`](http://ideone.com/hBAVpz)

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you very much, it works. Would you please make a formal answer and explain a little on pattern string so that I can vote? Mean while I would like to think the target substring 'UA0001A' may not be necessarily begin with '\', it may be '...\syx_UA0001A_...', so it will be seperated with a non  alphabet/number character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
s = '\\198.168.0.10\share\ccdfiles\UA-midd3-files\UA0001A_15_Jun_2014_08.17.49\Midd3\y12m05d25h03m16.midd3';
res = regexp(s, '(?i)\\(?![^\W_]*(midd|y\d+m\d+))(?=[^\W_]*\d)(?=[^\W_]*[a-zA-Z])([^\W_]+)','tokens');
disp(res{1}{1})
```

See [**the regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qL5jA9/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?i)` - the case-insensitive modifier
- `\\` - a literal backslash
- `(?![^\W_]*(midd|y\d+m\d+))` - a negative lookahead that will fail a match if there are `midd` or `y`+digits+`m`+digits after 0+ letters or digits
- `(?=[^\W_]*\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires at least 1 digit after 0+ digits or letters (`[^\W_]*`)
- `(?=[^\W_]*[a-zA-Z])` - there must be at least 1 letter after 0+ letters or digits
- `([^\W_]+)` - Group 1 (what will extract) matching 1+ letters or digits (or 1+ characters other than non-word chars and `_`).

The `'tokens'` "mode" will let you extract the captured value rather than the whole match.

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/hBAVpz)

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you! What if the target substring 'UA0001A' may not be necessarily begin with '\', it may be in '*\syx_UA0001A_*', so it will be separated with a non alphabet/number character?

Comment: Thank you very much, Wiktor!

Comment: You know, your rules are very generic, while the sample strings are very specific. I anchored the pattern at ``\``. If there can be `_`, replace ``\\`` with `(?:\\|_)`. See [`(?i)(?:\\|_)(?![^\W_]*(midd|y\d+m\d+))(?=[^\W_]*\d)(?=[^\W_]*[a-zA-Z])([^\W_]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qL5jA9/2).

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started:

```
[\\](?i)(?!.*midd.*)([a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*|[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)
```

- `[\\]` :  match a backslash
- `(?i)` : rest of regex is case insensitive
- `?!` following match can not match this
- `(?!.*midd.*)` : following match can not be a word wich has any character, midd, any character
- `([a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*|[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)` match at least one number followed by at least one letter OR at least one letter followed by at least one number followed by any amount of letters and numbers (**remember, cannot match the ?! group so no word which contains mid** )

Comment: Hi Ruben, thank you very much! but it seems (?!.*midd.*) remove everything. But I don't have enough knowledge to correct it. and ([a-z]+[0-9]+|[a-z]+[0-9]) part seems match UA0001, and graf3, etc., but not UA0001A

Comment: I am not sure why the ?! operator seems to break it for you. Can you provide a working code snippet in your question